# How to tell if a Scala reified type extends a certain parent class?

Tags: scala, types

In Scala, I am grabbing the type of a given class through its Scala manifest and storing it. My question is, how can I then check that type to see if the original class is descended from one parent class or another?

It looks like I can't perform a pattern match on `t: Class[MyParentClass]` because of type erasure, as below:

```
trait Product
trait PerishableProduct extends Product

class Fridge extends Product
class Banana extends PerishableProduct

def getProductType[P <: Product](implicit manifestP: Manifest[P]): Class[P] =
  manifestP.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[P]]

val isPerishable = getProductType[Fridge] match {
  case x: Class[PerishableProduct] => true
  case _ => false
}
// ^^ warning: non variable type-argument PerishableProduct in type pattern
// Class[PerishableProduct] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Is there another trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about good old reflection:

```
def isPerishable[P](implicit m: Manifest[P]): Boolean = 
  classOf[PerishableProduct].isAssignableFrom(m.erasure)

isPerishable[Fridge]   // false
isPerishable[Banana]   // true
```

Comment: Wow thanks Sciss - this works great. It even works with traits that take type parameters: `classOf[GroupedPerishableProduct[_]].isAssignableFrom(bananasType)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you need manifest when you are dealing with type erasure. Manifest provides an easy way to perform this test with <:<.

```
println( manifest[Fridge] <:< manifest[PerishableProduct] )
println( manifest[Banana] <:< manifest[PerishableProduct] )
```

The above have direct type references so to update getProductType for however it will be used.

```
def getProductType[P <: Product](implicit manifestP: Manifest[P]): Manifest[P] = manifestP
val isPerishable = getProductType[Fridge] <:< manifest[PerishableProduct]
println( isPerishable )
```

Comment: Many thanks **Neil** - I haven't encountered `<:<` before, it looks very useful. Unfortunately this won't work for me - because at the point of comparison I only have `manifestP.erasure.asInstanceOf[Class[P]]` available, not `manifest[P]`.

Answer (score 0):

a similar example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{FloatType, IntegerType, NumericType, StringType}

object test_subclass {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    Seq(IntegerType, FloatType, StringType)
      .map(e => {
        e match {
          case _:NumericType => 1
          case _ => 0
        }
      })
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
```

output:

```
1
1
0
```